# How can i connect to a sql server on a vm in azure?

Tags: azure

I have a vm in azure and on that vm is a sql server installed. I am using an app service that creates a connection to that server , but i get the error :

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the 
instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Is there a setting i am missing , in order to connect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The error you are facing is because SQL Server did not respond to the client request. This issue occurs due to multiple reasons. for me I got same error as I have 1433 port block on my network.**

- First of check your Server is up and running a check the instance name properly.
- Check if you have any firewall restricted on SQL server and whitelist required IP's.
- Port 1433 should be enabled as sql mostly open this port to connect.
- TCP/IP and Named Pipes protocols must be enabled. To enable it to go to SQL Server Configuration Manager >> SQL Server Network Configuration >> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER. now enable TCP/IP and Named Pipes protocols.
  [image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection